# Why is my site displaying differently In Firefox than in Safari?

Tags: html, css, firefox, safari

I manage a website called **ShareDen.com (http://shareden.com/home)** and it looks the right way in Mozilla Firefox and it's totally completely discombobulated in Safari. I Haven't tested it in other broswer's (still in process) however my guess is it looks horrible in IE 8.

Could it be because I just added the CSS **[Sticky Footer](http://www.cssstickyfooter.com/)** to my site? This wasn't happening before. Please help!

Thank you in advanced!

Comment: You might consider trying doctype.com

Comment: `application/xhtml+xml` is correct, if and only if you are serving perfectly valid XHMTL and have a doctype to that effect. Otherwise your site won't display at all in some browsers.

Comment: You're doctype is version 1.1 which is an XML application but you are serving your XHTML as text/html. Change your doctype to version 1.0.

Answer (score 4):

Start fixing [those errors](http://validator.w3.org/check?uri=http%3A%2F%2Fshareden.com%2Fhome&charset=%28detect+automatically%29&doctype=Inline&group=0) and retry. I suspect that it has to do with those lot of misnested tags which made Safari mad. The w3 errors points them out.

By the way, a `Content-Type` of `application/xhtml+xml` is not recommendable. Use `text/html`. It's after all just HTML.

Comment: Only Internet Explorer 7 and older doesn't support application/xhtml+xml. Every other browser I know supports it just fine.

Comment: @iconiK it's not that application/xhtml+xml isn't supported, it's that it assumes perfect xhtml which that page is clearly not using.

Comment: Besides, *in my humble opinion*, XHTML is overhyped. True, it's extremely helpful and useful when using it as a templating technlology for server side component based (MVC) frameworks (or anything else which ends up to get parsed by a XML tool which produces (X)HTML for the web), but everytime when one attempts to write or drag'n'drop all that XHTML together her/himself in plain text, a kitten dies.

Comment: Thanks everyone, I'll begin revising the sites code and fixing errors as I move along...

Comment: @iconiK - IE8 does not support application/xhtml+xml either.  

@BalusC - anything HTML can do, XHTML can do better.

Comment: XHTML is indeed better when you want to use a XML tool to parse/generate/validate/whatever HTML. But for the remnant it offers no advantages. Webbrowsers can take both as good.